# Oracle sql query for aggregation of data

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to dispaly the output as follows using oracle sql query

**input:**

```
name col1 col2      
A     11    12      
B     12    10
```

**Output:**

```
name col1 col2  tot    
A     11    12  23    
B     10    10  20    
tot    21   22  43
```

Comment: The output for your B col1 values does not match the input.

Comment: See [rollup](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/rollup-cube-grouping-functions-and-grouping-sets.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select coalesce(name, 'Tot') name, 
       sum(col1) col1, 
       sum(col2) col2, 
       sum(col1+col2) tot
from myTable
group by rollup(name)
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/74ffb/2).

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is handled quite directly using `group by with rollup`:

```
select coalesce(name, 'tot'), sum(col1) as col1, sum(col2) as col2, sum(col1+col2) as total
from t
group by name with rollup
order by (case when name is null then 1 else 0 end), name
```